# I dont know how to finish proving this statement using an indirect proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

The problem is

$$\forall j \in \Bbb{Z} \, , \, 4j − 1 \text{ is prime } \implies j \text{ is odd}.$$

I did: assume $j$ is even
let $j =2k$ $k \notin \Bbb{Z}$
$2k \notin \Bbb{Z}+ 
4^2k - 1$ not Prime

I dont know what to do next

Comment: When j=2, 7 is prime, but 2 is even.

Comment: Yep plenty of counterexamples here. $j=6$ is another.

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall j \in \Bbb{Z} \, , \, 4j − 1 \text{ is prime } \implies j \text{ is odd}.$$

This proposition if false, so all you to do is to present a counter example.

*Proof*. The proposition if false. For example, let $j = 2$. Then $j \in \Bbb{Z}$ is such that $4j-1 = 7$ is prime, but $2$ is not odd. $\square$

Why is it enough to present a counter example? I’ll explain.

If you want to prove that $\forall x, p(x)$ is false, you can do it by showing that its negation is true. By *De Morgan*’s laws, we have that the negation of this proposition is $\exists x \colon \neg p(x)$. And to show that this latter is true, you have to prove the existence of some object $x$ such that $\neg p(x)$ is true (i.e., such that $p(x)$ is false).